# How does R function summary.glm calculate the covariance matrix for glm model?

Tags: r, regression, covariance

I would like to know how the covariance matrix of estimated coefficients is actually calculated. The code uses QR-decomposition and inversion of some sort. I have an idea that it would go something like this:

$(X'X)^{-1}=[(QR)'QR]^{-1}=(R'R)^{-1}=\Sigma$

Could someone explain the code?

```
p <- object$rank    
p1 <- 1L:p
Qr <- qr.lm(object)
covmat.unscaled <- chol2inv(Qr$qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE])
covmat <- dispersion * covmat.unscaled
```

Comment: Welcome Kati. You use the dollar sign before and after your equation for it to be displayed as math.

Comment: before apply $X'X$ you need to subtract the mean for each column, otherwise it will not be covariance matrix

Answer (score 4):

I was confused about this several months ago. After reading some material, I have a clue about the problem. But I am not sure that the following is correct.

Suppose the distribution of response $Y$ is an exponential family, $X^TX>0$. $p(Y|\eta)\sim \exp(\phi^{-1}\eta^T T(Y)-A(\eta)+B(Y))$, $\eta=g(E(Y|X))=X\beta$, $g$ is the  canonical link, $\phi$ is the dispersion parameter of the distribution.

Fitting GLM uses MLE, and we have the Wald-type CI for MLE. The variance-covariance matrix is $I(\hat\beta)^{-1}$. $I(\hat\beta)=-E(\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\beta^2}\log p(Y|\eta)|\hat\beta)=\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\beta^2}A(X\beta)|\hat\beta=X^T(\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial\eta^2}A(\eta)|\hat\eta )X=X^TWX$. Here $W$ is a diagonal matrix with weights. The variance-covariance matrix is $(X^TWX)^{-1}$.

Edit: 
An easier way is to use $I(\beta)=(\dfrac{d \eta}{d \beta})^TI(\eta)\dfrac{d \eta}{d \beta}$.

reference:

[exponential family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)

[Fisher information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information)

Comment: Many thanks for this - that's really helpful - I think this is right! Checked the other answer as the correct one as it addressed my question more closely, but +1!

Answer (score 3):

`?chol2inv` says:

> Invert a symmetric, positive definite square matrix from its
>        Choleski decomposition.  Equivalently, compute (X'X)^(-1) from the
>        (R part) of the QR decomposition of X.

and if you want to dig deeper into the numerics:

> This is an interface to the LAPACK routine ‘DPOTRI’

and the [documentation for DPOTRI](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d7a/group__double_p_ocomputational_ga9dfc04beae56a3b1c1f75eebc838c14c.html) says:

> DPOTRI computes the inverse of a real symmetric positive definite
>    matrix A using the Cholesky factorization `A = U**T*U` or A = `L*L**T`
>    computed by DPOTRF. [here `**T` denotes transposition]

The point is that once you have the $R$ component, you don't need to take the crossproduct and *then* invert - you can much more easily compute the inversion directly.

Hence, the `chol2inv(Qr$qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE])` computes $(R^\top R)^{-1}=(X^\top WX)^{-1}$, where $R$ is the upper triangular matrix from the QR decomposition $QR(\sqrt{W}X)$.

Comment: Many thanks for this - get it now! Oh yes and would you also know if what I did here to calculate 95% confidence intervals on nnls estimates by using bbmle's mle2 is correct? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/373253/calculating-the-p-values-in-a-constrained-least-squares/405606#405606